# Speech Recognizer plugin issue in Phonegap 2.9.1

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, speech-recognition

I am using Phonegap 2.9.1 in eclipse. 
I want to use https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer plugin. But it is saying "window is undefined" error while adding the plugin "cordova add plugin SpeechRecognizer"

So please help how to add this plugin in phonegap 2.9.1

If possible please provide any other plugin for SpeechRecognizer in phonegap 2.9.1

Comment: don't use phonegap 2.9.1, if you want to submit the app to google play you will need at least 3.5.1

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But can you give me the download link of phonegap 3.5.1 bcoz i m new to phonegap.

Comment: There is no download link, you have to install node and then install phonegap using this command "npm install -g phonegap"

Comment: i install phonegap 3.5.1 but the SpeechRecognizer plugin still can't work

Comment: with the same error?

Comment: yes....one more question that can you provide step by step method for phonegap installation in eclipse and then installing plugin in it ?

Comment: No, I can't, phonegap can't be installed on eclipse, you can use the CLI to create the project, add android platform and install the plugin, and then import the project created on platforms/android on eclipse

Comment: thanks for your support i solved my error